# Unity Android: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper"

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm building a Unity Android app that makes use of some native android libraries. I had all of this nicely set up and working until I tried to move the calls to the native code onto another thread for performance reasons.

I first had the issue of the JNI not liking the threading, so adding in a
`AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread();` call fixed that fatal error. However now there is a new, non-fatal exception being thrown repeatedly and causing my native code to not work.

The stacktrace is below, but it seems to be centered around the lack of a `com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper` class not being found by the JVM.

Does anyone have any ideas where this could be going wrong?

```
02-02 15:25:05.194 10248-10416/com.limoncello.androidtest E/mono: Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for UnityEngine.AndroidReflection ---> UnityEngine.AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x0008c] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/AndroidJNISafe.cs:24 
at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.FindClass (System.String name) [0x0000f] in /Users/builduser/buildsla
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but I ran into the same problem.

I was calling static methods Java from Unity3D on android from a non-user interface thread from Unity3D. what fixed it for me was doing the

```
jc = new AndroidJavaClass("domain.yourthing.yourclassname");
```

in the main unity3d thread. calling those(after doing the attach) seems to work fine from the other c# threads.